# Button Style is not working, linked to external css

Tags: html, css, button, vs-web-site-project

This is my code for the button in HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./Styles/main.css" />
</head>


<body>

    <a href="bells.html" class="buttonEnterClasses"> <button>Enter Classes</button></a> 


</body>


</html>
```

Its Linked to this Stylesheet in css:

```css
/*CSS for the  Enter Classes Button in Index.Html*/
.buttonEnterClasses{
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #d5a32d !important;
  color: #fff !important;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 0;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: visible;
    font: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
    color: inherit;
    text-transform: none;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0 30px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: .875rem;
    line-height: 38px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: .1s ease-in-out;
    transition-property: all;
    transition-property: color,background-color,border-color; 
    touch-action: manipulation;
}

.buttonEnterClasses a:hover {
  opacity:1;
}
```

But the thing is the button keeps on appearing weirdly like this:
[click here to see preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enBOQ.png)

It would be greatly appreciated if someone can help me fix this and make it so the default white area is gone and instead looks something like this:
[click here to see preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wh3Wt.png)

Thanks :)

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. `<button>` cannot be a child of an anchor. In addition, the `<link>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we go. Just removed `<button>`, we don't need it here.

```css
/*CSS for the  Enter Classes Button in Index.Html*/
.buttonEnterClasses{
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #d5a32d !important;
  color: #fff !important;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 0;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: visible;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
    color: inherit;
    text-transform: none;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0 30px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: .875rem;
    line-height: 38px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: .1s ease-in-out;
    transition-property: all;
    transition-property: color,background-color,border-color; 
    touch-action: manipulation;
}

.buttonEnterClasses a:hover {
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./Styles/main.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <a href="bells.html" class="buttonEnterClasses">Enter Classes</a> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: its not against the rules, and I didn't steel your answer my friend, anyway I will give +1 don't worry its not a big deal, usually one issue have the same answer if most people mind.